# divide by zero exception in ARM OMAP3515 processor

Tags: embedded, omap

I am using OMAP3515 processor (Generic CortexA8 Device) for my project, I was working on exception handling but this processor dos not generate any exception when any divide by zero instruction is given , it simply goes not next instruction.
I want to know whether any configuration available to generate divide by zero exception.

Comment: Are you sure you're not dividing a floating-point operand by zero?

Comment: perhaps you need to enable the exceptions?

Comment: Hi , I have enabled FPSCR for DZE but even then it is not going to any exception.

Answer (score 2):

Cortex A8 does not support divide-by-zero for integer operations.  Other than normal interrupts and debug exceptions, the only fault [exceptions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344f/Beigaeaj.html) supported are *data abort*, *prefetch abort*, and *undefined instruction*

The VFP supports divide-by-zero exceptions for floating point operations, which must be explicitly enabled via the [FPSCR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344f/Chdfafia.html) DZE bit.

Comment: Hi , I have enabled FPSCR for DZE but even then it is not going to any exception.

Comment: @vivek : Earilier you said you were not using floating-point, so I would not expect an FP exception.  If you are using floating point if the hardware enabled ([FPEXC:EN](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344f/Ccdhcfga.html))?  And is hardware divide supported ([MVFR0:D](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344f/Chdebegb.html)) on your target?  Have you built your code for hardware floating point (VFP) support?  See also [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/Beihdjje.html) i.e. RTFM.